# Is there any way to read the file present in change list using python perforce?

Tags: python, perforce, p4v

I have change list. I am able to list out the files present in change list but I want to load the file present in change list with the changes. Is there any way using python perforce scripting?

Comment: Try starting here: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.programming.html

Comment: I am listing files using `p4.run_describe("-s",changelist_no)`. i am trying to load the file using `p4.run_print(file@changelist)` to get the modified file contene. but its returning file content from depot file not the modified one. -@Bryan Pendleton

Comment: Is the changelist already submitted? Or is it still pending?

Comment: still in pending.

Comment: The `-s` flag to describe is asking for "short" description, which includes only the file name, and no diffs. If you remove the `-s`, you will get the diffs. Or you could use the `diff` command. The `print` command never prints differences between local files and depot files, it only ever prints depot files, so that's not the command to run.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you're currently listing out the files, but I assume it's some form of the `p4 files` command, using either the CLI or the P4Python API?  In either case, use `p4 describe` (on the changelist) to see the diffs, or `p4 print` (on the revisions returned by `p4 files`) to get the content of an individual file.

Comment: Using python p4v scripting api's i am listing files using `p4.run_describe("-s",changelist_no)`. i am trying to load the file using `p4.run_print(file@changelist)` to get the modified file contene. but its returning file content from depot file not the modified one.